# What are the Speeds and Performance for OpsHubs TFS migration to VSO?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, opshub

- What does OpsHub say the migrations speeds are per changeset with The
  VSO Migration Utility?
- Does the commercial OpsHub Integration Manager tool improve the
  performance?

One of our projects has 72,000 changesets and labels and our first attempt was still running after 3 weeks and had only got less than half way.

- How does the VSO Migration Utility manage with changing TFS 2010
  codebase while migrating?
- Developers are changing code while the migration is happening is this
  advised?
- Does ongoing file changes slow the migration? Does it matter? 
  If the migration takes weeks then it's the only option.
- If the tool does not manage file changes while the migration is
  taking place how do we update VSO afterwards with the new changes?

Answer (score 1):

For our utility, your dev team can continue using your on-premises TFS without any hassle. The utility will automatically detect those changes and migrate them in sequence. (This goes for both workitem and source control)

The only side effect is that **in the tool** the count at the end of the migration will be shown as ACTUAL MIGRATED/COUNT DETECTED AT START OF MIGRATION.
And where the former is greater than the latter. eg. 2000/1500. This however is only user interface limited and does not effect your actual migration.

And no, on-going migration is not hindered in terms of speed by changes in your TFS instance. I am assuming you are using the v1.5.0.00 of the utility.
We are working on our next release which focuses greatly on performance improvements. We'll update you once the release is out, it should help you achieve migration in much shorter time span.

Comment: Thanks. Roughly what is the time per 1000 changesets?

Comment: Time per changeset is a very generic measurement. Because the size of the data in question could vary in our dataset and yours. But through our testing metrics we are projecting about 2.5x to 3x performance in speed.